# See resulting tsconfig when using { "extends": ... }

Tags: typescript, webstorm, tsconfig

I'm using WebStorm with my Angular project, so I have a lot of different tsconfig files (`tsconfig.json`, `tsconfig.lib.json`, `tsconfig.lib.prod.json` and `tsconfig.spec.json`).

Now most of the configuration is only in `tsconfig.json`, while all other extend this config. But there are also some cases, where a config is in multiple extended files and I'm wondering if they can be moved to the main file.

Is there a way to see the full `tsconfig.lib.json`, with the extended options?

AFAIK: Visual Studio had this option for its web.config files.

Comment: no, there is no such feature.If you miss it, feel free to file a feature request to youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`--showConfig`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) CLI argument to get the extended config file  as output.

> Rather than actually execute a build with the other input options and config files, show the final implied config file in the output.

Example:

```
tsc -p path/to/tsconfig.lib.json --showConfig
```